# Reverse a 1-dimensional array

Tags: code-golf, string, array

*Note: [This challenge](/questions/75687) is not the same.*

## Challenge

Believe it or not, we haven't got ONE challenge for reversing one-dimensional arrays (although we've got one for n-dimensional ones)! This should operate only on the 1st dimension, not on all dimensions of an array.

## Rules

- Standard loopholes are **denied**
- **`[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`** becomes **`[[3, 4], [1, 2]]`**, not **`[[4, 3], [2, 1]]`**.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), but no answer is accepted. Go beat the others!
- You can get the array any way, except hardcoding. You can also get a string and process it.
- The input will be an array (yes, commas or no commas, it needs to be an array).

## Test cases

These are the test cases:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 'hello', 'world!']
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 1]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

These are the supposed results:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1]
['world!', 'hello', 2, 1]
[[2, 3, 4, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
[23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You may accept input as `[1 2 3 4]`, or even `1 2 3 4`, or any other form or array your language has.

Comment: The empty array and a single-element array would probably be good test cases.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of the [very rigid input format](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8077/8478). You've chosen one specific way languages denote arrays which gives an arbitrary benefit to all languages using this syntax. Other languages might not use `,` as separators (but only spaces), or use `;` instead, and some might use `()` or `{}` instead of `[]`. On top of that, many languages don't support arrays of mixed type, or strings at all. It's normally a good idea to allow people to take the array in the most natural form for their language.

Comment: "*Believe it or not, we haven't got ONE challenge for reversing one-dimensional arrays*" Probably because it's extremely trivial. One byte in both Pyth and Jelly.

Comment: @Doorknob I don't think simple challenges are a problem. But since they are only interesting in languages which *don't* have built-ins for them (i.e. esolangs in this case), it's a bit pointless to pose a simple challenge without making it as inclusive for all languages as possible.

Comment: Do we need to take input as a string, or an array? Some of the specifications you list look like you want strings, but none of the active answers do it that way.

Comment: @Doorknob And it would be one byte in Vitsy, save for the rigid input format.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Well, that IS the challenge! (replying to very rigid input format comment)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος That's also why the challenge is so unpopular: if you want to make a challenge about string processing, make a challenge about string processing. But making a challenge that is seemingly about reversing an array, but then is dominated by string processing in arbitrary set of languages (while it can be solved with a single built-in in languages that get the string processing for free because the format happens to match their syntax), is mostly not in the spirit of this community.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I have specified that both arrays and strings are allowed.

Comment: But we still have the strict output format.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I don't see anywhere that we are supposed to output to stdout, even less that there's a strict output format.

Comment: See the Molecule answer.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy if this is only in a comment on a submission, you can practically ignore it, as it isn't in the specs

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy I changed output format, although I didn't like that change at all.

Answer (score 13):

## Jelly, 1 byte

```
Ṛ
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bma&input=&args=WzEsIDIsIFszLDRdXQ) It reverses an array. <sub>(yay this is my first Jelly answer!)</sub>

Comment: Oh, there **is** a flat version of U? I've always been using U'...

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth, <s>2</s> 1 byte<s>s</s>

*1 byte off thanks to Doorknob*

```
_
```

`_` is reverse, and Pyth takes implicit input. Yes, my first Pyth answer is an underscore.

Comment: All of a sudden, +2! Yay! (Maybe my username change...)

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 8 bytes

```
reversed
```

This is too short.

Comment: `reversed` is the name for a built in function in python that takes an iterable and reverses it.

Comment: I think this returns an iterable, not an array.

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Where does it say the output has to be an array

Answer (score 6):

## , 3 bytes

```
ᴚ
```

Literally reverses array. Implicitly performs I/O.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 16 bytes

```
lambda x:x[::-1]
```

This isn't even enough characters to post as an answer.

Comment: Clever! *8 more to go...*

Answer (score 4):

## C, 65 bytes

Takes a pointer to the start of the list and a list length.

```
void f(int*a,int s){int t=*a;*a=a[--s];a[s--]=t;if(s>1)f(a+1,s);}
```

This is a recursive algorithm that swaps the first element with the last, and then runs the same function on the middle.

Ungolfed:

```
void f(int* a, int s){
  int t = a[0];
  a[0] = a[--s];
  a[s--] = t;
  if(s > 1){
    f(a + 1, s - 2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 19 bytes

```
print input()[::-1]
```

Comment: Hold on... doesn't python 2 have 'raw_input()' instead of 'input()'?

Comment: @TuukkaX Yes, but that returns a string. In python 2, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(input())` meaning it returns a list instead of a string in this instance. Python 3 is significantly longer: `print(eval(input()[::-1]))` (26 chars)

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ Oh. Thanks for telling O.o!

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandHamDJ We count in bytes, not chars, tho.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

Code:

```
R
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=Ug&input=W1sxLCAyLCAzLCA0XSwgWzIsIDMsIDQsIDFdXQ).

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
r.
```

which expects a list as Input and unifies the reverse with the Output.

#### Alternative

```
rw
```

which expects a list as Input and writes the reverse to `STDOUT`.

Comment: @Downvoter any reason why this answer is less interesting than all others?

Comment: That guy seems to have down voted every answer.

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy well that's interesting…

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy Except possibly the OP's answer. I checked before and after, but I can't be sure because I don't have 750 rep.

Comment: Nope, that's downvoted too.

Comment: The only non-downvoted one from May 2 is the Jelly answer...

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>62</s> <s>38</s> 30 bytes

```java
java.util.Collections::reverse
```

Modifies the input-`ArrayList` instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

-8 bytes thanks to *@OliverGrégoire*.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##tZBNa8MwDIbv/RVaTgl4Zk732X3A2HXrDj2OHdzE25w5drCVlDLy2zO5DXSXQhkULGxZj/S@diU7eeoaZavyeyiMDAFepLY/EwBtUfkPWSiYxxSgc7qEIq2ohbeoDX/WAe9el5Uq8AFMdktUT0FrDhbuYdihT84YwrSzYTbzqlM@qCE2NO3S6AICSqRtI1GTgXSBXtvPt3eQ2VY92oKaplq12iTpRhBgjx9UAYneVR@9l@vAZYhYKhjkDKYMzscxNbe8SGPXeLFYB1Q1dy3yhrygsX@rB41PvpQxLqHDynlTniRH0TrgiWxv80gwENkRP2IrccHgksEVg2sGN6R4RkF1QYAgQkQXxAiCBFGCMEFcTlwe5xCXT//jsp/0wy8)

---

With an array as input instead of `ArrayList` (**62 bytes)**:

```java
import java.util.*;a->{Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(a));}
```

Modifies the input-array instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##vZBLT8MwEITv@RVLTwlyU5zyVAQS4goFqdwQBzdxqYNrR/amVVXlt4fNQ604cEOVbMk7@TwzcSE2YmxLaYr8u1Hr0jqEgrS4QqXj8xQAJhN4EyTbJeBKwmKHcpzZymAQZFp4Dy9CmX0AoAxKtxSZhFk7AmysyiELXxeFzPDjE0SUkl7TpuVRoMpgBgbuoRHjh/2T1ZpAZY2PndxI52X46JzY@Vj4Z@UxFFGU1k3aG5TVQpPB4NNlralJOEenzFcX19c45KP0SGFGbg/anjNIGEwZXNZpR5s4C1sw6sf5zqNcx7bCuCRf1CY8vs/QLpeyfLd9bn93uPx34GgltbYjOmyt0/nZ6ETp7UA@v3@cwVEeNAa8PumD9KFXDK4Z3DC4ZXBHHS5o03dOACeCt72I4QRxojhhnLiEuKT1IS6Z/nvvOqibHw)

---

Looping over the array to reverse it would be **<s>75</s> 69 bytes** instead:

```java
a->{Object t;for(int i=0,j=a.length;i<--j;a[i++]=a[j],a[j]=t)t=a[i];}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##vZBNbsIwEIX3nGLKKgjHwqG/clOpByhd0B3Kwk0M2DVOlAwghHL2dIIRVRfdVUi25Rl/fu/ZVu1UXFba2@Kry51qGnhTxh8HAMajrpcq1zDrS4BdaQrIo/dPq3NcZKBGkvotTRoNKjQ5zMBDCp2KX46BA5TLso5IDEw6YTZV3Gm/wrU0z3FspVqY8ThL1cJmrF9SHCFVJpNtJ4N0tf10JH12OKXYUMZojrXxq1OQEPCSDHWDFMPr/aV3FAwSBlMGt6080Z7nUQ@OQjk/NKg3vNwir0gXnY8sfQ7fonH8ta7VoeGF1tVHGXzD3fPlvw2Ha@1cOaTNvqxdcTO8kntfkM7vhzP4aZ97DER71Q8JpncM7hk8MHhk8EQZJjTpXBAgiBB9LmIEQYIoQZggLiEu6XWIS6b/nrsdtN03)

-5 bytes thanks to *@OliverGrégoire*.

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##vZDNbsIwEITvPMWWUxCOVYf@yk2lPkDpgd4QB5MYSGrsKF5ACOXZ0w2OqHrorUKKI@/k88zEpdqr2FXalvlXmxnlPbyrwp4GAIVFXa9UpmHajQB7V@SQRR/LUmc4X4AaSdIbWvR4VFhkMAULKbQqfj0FDlCuXB2RGfg0Fkynihtt17iR47F/iWMt1dwvUjXXC9a9Uhxh2kmyaWXwrnZLQ959xLnGlkpGM6wLuz43CQ0v1VB7pB5WHy7aSTBIGEwY3DXyTFueRR04CuPs6FFvudshr8gXjY1Kuh2@w8Lwt7pWR89zratPF3LD2f7w34HDjTbGDWlzcLXJb4ZXSu8G8vn94wx@5F5jIJqrXkgIvWfwwOCRwRODZ@pwS4u@CwIEEaLrRYwgSBAlCBPEJcQlnQ9xyeTfezeDpv0G) for the loop.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire 69 you mean: `a->{Object t;for(int s=0,e=a.length;s<--e;a[s++]=a[e],a[e]=t)t=a[s];}` ;) But thanks

Comment: Yes, I don't know where my mind was. Sorry... Also, for the api-answer, `java.util.Collections::reverse` (30 bytes) should be enough, because a list is an array, conceptually speaking.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yeah, I had `l->{java.util.Collections.reverse(l);}` at first, but "_The input will be an array (yes, commas or no commas, it needs to be an array)._" sounded like I couldn't use a List. But I now realize he means it must be an array/list/set/etc. and cannot be a String.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 14 bytes

you can't get simpler than this:

```
->a{a.reverse}
```

Comment: If you want more idiomatic Ruby, `a.method:reverse` is only two bytes longer.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript ES6, 14 bytes

```
x=>x.reverse()
```

Simple enough. Anonymous lambda that reverses an array.

Comment: Couldn't you do `x.reverse` as well? It returns a `function` object which, when called, returns the reversed version of `x`, which is exactly what this one does.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Nope. `x.reverse` is the general method inherited from the Array prototype. For you solution to work, we'd have to re-bind it to the original instance, as `x=>x.reverse.bind(x)`

Comment: Oh, I see. Darn, that'd have saved a few bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 1 byte

```
R
```

`R`everses the input list. These are words to make this answer long enough.

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 34 bytes

```
DEF R A
DIM T[LEN(A)]RSORT T,A
END
```

`RSORT` actually just sorts the arrays, and then reverses them.

#### Cheating answer: (requires turning the screen upside down):

```
LINPUT S$ATTR 2?S$
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 12 bytes

```
list.reverse
```

Surprised nobody else used this.
Reverses in place, but I don't think there are any restrictions on that.

Answer (score 1):

## Jolf, 1 + 1 = 2 bytes

```
_
```

[Try it here!](http://ethproductions.github.io/Jolf/#code=Xw&input=WzEsMiwzLCJoZWxsbywgd29ybGQhIiwid29ybGQiLFszLDQsNV1d) (bonus for polyglot with Pyth?) `_` reverses (negates) an array. (Make sure pretty output is on.)

Comment: Why did you add 1?

Comment: @msh210 1 byte to ensure the pretty print option is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 1 byte

```
_
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=_&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+%27hello%27%2C+%27world%21%27%5D)

Pyke has implicit input and output. Polyglot with Pyth, Jolf,

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 11 bytes

A subroutine:

```
{reverse@_}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 1 byte

Nothing interesting. Keg has a built-in. (Since Keg does not have any other means of representing an array, let's assume the stack is the array (and in fact it is).)

```
?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///f/v//xOKUNAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 16 bytes

```
lambda l:l[::-1]
```

*Please examine this answer again. I was a bit lazy answering this :P*

Thanks to 55749 (J843136028) for suggesting to convert this to a function :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Molecule](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/molecule), 8 bytes

```
I"Ar"+`n
```

Explanation:

```
I"Ar"+`n
I"Ar"    Read input, append the command (reverse array) as a string.
     +   concatenate the 2 strings
      `n set the program's source code to that new string.
```

Simple I/O:

```
Input    | Output
[5 "n"]    [n 5.0]
['n 3]     [3.0 n]
```

Comment: This isn't the correct output format, unfortunately.

Comment: yeah, but that's just because this language doesn't do commas between objects while creating arrays.

Comment: As much as I'd agree with you, this challenge requires a strict I/o format.

Comment: There is no longer a strict input format, I think.

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 61 bytes

It beats C! \o/

It simply fill a new table in the reversed order.

```lua
function f(g)h={}for i=0,#g do h[#g-i]=g[i+1]end return h end
```

It could have been done by working on the pointer, suppressing the return statement and the new table definition, but it actually is longer by 2 bytes

```lua
function f(g)for i=1,#g/2 do x=#g-i+1g[x],g[i]=g[i],g[x]end end
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MySQL](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5341), 64 bytes

```
set@=1;select a from(select a,@:=@+1 n from t order by n desc)u;
```

Tested on 5.6.24.

My first SQL answer; please provide feedback!

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 17 bytes

```
$r=array_reverse;
```

call `$r($array)`

non-built-in version, 53 bytes:

```
function r($a){while($a)$b[]=array_pop($a);return$b;}
```

call `r($array)`

generator for PHP >= 5.5, 45 bytes

```
function y($a){while($a)yield array_pop($a);}
```

usage: `foreach(y($array)as$v)var_dump($v);`

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 16 bytes

```
seq(Ans(I),I,dim(Ans),1,~1
```

No built-ins for reversing an array in TI-Basic...

Answer (score 0):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 7 bytes

```
.).
IER
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/X09Tj8vTNej//2hDHQUjHQX1jNScnHx1IKM8vygnRVE9FgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), 43 bytes

```
	main dab
	dab - a
-
	- dip
a
	dot dab
	dot
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/58zNzEzTyElMYmLE0go6CokculyceoqpGQWcCUCxfJLoJL5Jf///zf8b/TfGAA)

(the `-` function subtracts and `a` is `lambda x: [sum(x[1:]), sum(x)]`. So `dab - a` takes the first element of a list)

Comment: I think that you could argue you define a function `R` [like this](https://tio.run/##S8lPyS/@/z@IizNIISUxiYsTSCjoKiRy6XJx6iqkZBZwJQLF8kugkvkl////N/xv9N8YAA).

Answer (score 0):

## [Preproc](https://gitlab.com/pavelb/Preproc), 279 bytes

```
#define v(x)Z(Z(Z(Z(Z(x)))))
#define Z(x)Y(Y(Y(Y(Y(x)))))
#define Y(x)X(X(X(X(X(x)))))
#define X(x)e(e(e(e(e(x)))))
#define e(x,...)x
#define d()
#define s(x,y,...)y
#define r(x,y...)i(x,,R d d d d()()()()()(y)x)
#define C,
#define R()r
#define i(x,v...)s d()(C##x v)
v(r e()(I))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY49C8MgEEB3f4WQ5Q4OoV9L1zQFlw6Z2q7VQpY2GBD99dZL0YC@Rd/jDmdnZ/d9pdQZ@54@VnoI@IRCQD6iRBYPKDSRxR0KTWRhodDELEgphaEaA1tdco1rj9U5dqymfKFRmj@AlYhhW9FTvY6Arj542vOaZZ3tuy5Ij8KDy39C0Igppctw1bfhrMWO9nSgI51@)

---

Some notes.

- Because the language (one pass of the C preprocessor) is not Turing-complete (as far as I know), this can only process arrays up to a fixed size. That can be increased by making `v(x)` evaluate `e(x)` more times.
- Input on command line, separated with `,` (please only give non-negative integers)
- Output on stdout, separated with spaces.
- My first Preproc answer. Golfing suggestions are appreciated.
- I would appreciate it if someone explain why do I need 4 nested `d`.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte

Nothing interesting. MathGolf has a built-in.

```
x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/7/i//9odUMjdR11I0P1WAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 byte

```apl
⊖
```

This works both on lists of lists and proper multi-dimensional arrays.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZC7TsMwFIb3PsVPli6uhBPuKwzAQCXCVnVwidtGOLHlJlSdkTJUcgVCsMETILHwBDyKXyQcQwcGLsPx@aXz@T8XYVQvWwilJ23rl4/t2De33q388sa7F@/e3l8T39z51UN6fkjvxfFJ2lI@TftnGGOtugPOEDMkDFvDbufXejSVSumIxFxblW1EP8Pf3RgGa8nAh3@ZfzHbDDsMuwx7DPv0ZZOC6pwATgQPNsRwgjhRnDBOXExcHHyIi5PQxj1BXssSNOnVDPMpSWO1kRZFraq8l@WFLGe5LoWCsFYsDjo0knsO9/s82P@7IDS51IURVqJfV6auIMoMR3JUT@Cb@w8)